# Gradle project with no project classes but with some buildscript-accessible custom classes?

Tags: sql, gradle

I am thinking to use Gradle to manipulate with mysql database. It will read some files from filesystem, analyse them and populate database accordingly.

Such project will not produce any project code, because all output will go to database tables. On the other hand, gradle script should access some custom java or groovy classes to facilitate working with source data.

Is this a possible Gradle usage? Where to put gradle-accessible classes then? I don't want to have separate project, producing JAR for this project. I wan't single project, so that Gradle first compiles classes and the utilizes them in the script.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is extensible, so you can utilize [`buildSrc`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources) for such scenarios. It works in the following way:

- along `build.gradle` in the project there is `buildSrc` dir with custom `build.gradle`
- in `buildSrc/build.gradle` you can define the script dependencies itself, implement plugins and tasks
- finally you can apply a plugin from `buildSrc` to `build.gradle`.

It's quite handy, since e.g. IntelliJ can import such project and provide code completion for instance.

Another way is to put all the necessary stuff in `build.gradle` itself.

Such `buildSrc` project can be compiled to a jar, published and provided as a plugin, or it can be a separate project on github to be downloaded and used to manipulate data. Also, there no need to implement `Plugin`, you can use static methods e.g. Have a look at the [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/42716280).